# A Bizzare Java IO failure, explained

Tags: java, memory, file-io

Here's the guilty code:

```
// Demo the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error.

    import java.util.*;

    public class Bozo {

      void TstReadFile() {
        SubBozo sb = new SubBozo();
        sb.readFile();
      }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Bozo b = new Bozo();
      b.TstReadFile();
    }
  }


/** Read in the observing list file. */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SubBozo {

  public boolean readFile() {

    int lineCt = 0;          // Count the lines read in observingList.

    long heap,
         heapMaxSize,
         heapFreeSize;

    String s = "Unstarted";

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
      fis = new FileInputStream("../data/observingList");
      in = new DataInputStream(fis);
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Couldn't open ../data/observingList because " +
                         e.getMessage());
    }

    boolean go = true;
    while (go) {
      try {
        s = br.readLine();  // Lines should not be longer than say 256 characters.
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't read ../data/observingList because " +
                           e.getMessage());
        heap = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
        heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
        heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("" + lineCt + ") " + "Total Memory (MB): " +
                           (heap / 1048576) + "\n  Heap Max Size (MB): " +
                           (heapMaxSize / 1048576) +
                           "\n  Heap Free Size (MB): " +
                           (heapFreeSize / 1048576));
        go = false;
      }

      if ((lineCt++ % 1000) == 0) {
        System.gc();
        heap = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
        heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
        heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("" + lineCt + ") " + "Total Memory (MB): " +
                           (heap / 1048576) + "\n  Heap Max Size (MB): " +
                           (heapMaxSize / 1048576) +
                           "\n  Heap Free Size (MB): " +
                           (heapFreeSize / 1048576));
      }
    }

    try {
      br.close();
      in.close();
      fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Couldn't close the input file stream because " +
                         e.getMessage());
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

When this is run, with the command:

nebula:finderChart/src java Bozo

It throws an out of memory error.  Here's the printout:

1) Total Memory (MB): 119
  Heap Max Size (MB): 1776
  Heap Free Size (MB): 118

1001) Total Memory (MB): 119
  Heap Max Size (MB): 1776
  Heap Free Size (MB): 119

2001) Total Memory (MB): 119
  Heap Max Size (MB): 1776
  Heap Free Size (MB): 119

3001) Total Memory (MB): 119
  Heap Max Size (MB): 1776
  Heap Free Size (MB): 119

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:515)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:306)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:345)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
        at SubBozo.readFile(SubBozo.java:34)
        at Bozo.TstReadFile(Bozo.java:10)
        at Bozo.main(Bozo.java:15)

Now for the bizzare part, but I suspect you've already seen it.  Every 1000 lines the JVM prints out its memory usage.  It's not runing out of memory.

When the error is thrown, it misses the catch:

try {

```
 s = br.readLine();
```

} catch (Exception e) {

```
 System.out.println("Couldn't read ../data/observingList because " 
 ...
```

}

So let's try increasing memory:
 java  -Xmx1024m Bozo

Same result, so I won't repeat it.

What happened is that the file being read, obasrvingList, had some very long (> 2048 bytes) lines in it.  This freaked out Java, but it wasn't until I tried to edit the file in Vim and found that vim couldn't edit it, that it became apparent that insanely long lines are a problem for a text reader in general.

TIA

Tom

Comment: This is... thorough, but... what's your question?

Comment: An `OutOfMemoryError` isn't an exception: `OutOfMemoryError extends VirtualMachineError extends Error extends Throwable extends Object`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not asking any questions, but here are some answers:

> When the error is thrown, it misses the catch:

Because you are catching `Exception`, `OutOfMemoryError` is not extending it. And thank god because you are ignoring the stack trace while logging the exception:

```
System.out.println("Couldn't read ../data/observingList because " +
                       e.getMessage());
```

Instead always use:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

or **better** - use some logging framework.

> It's not runing out of memory.

Well, it is. It tries to allocate an array that is way too big (say: you have 50 MiB free and it tries to allocate 60 MiB). This is how `StringBuffer` works - doubling the size of internal array while keeping a reference to an old and a new one for a moment.

> What happened is that the file being read, obasrvingList, had some very long (> 2048 bytes) lines in it. This freaked out Java, but it wasn't until I tried to edit the file in Vim

I can assure you that 2048 characters is nothing for a JVM. I suspect the problematic lines had at least several millions of characters... Even [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) failed to open that file (probably the most optimized editor ever), so the lines are probably insanely long.

Also I have few suggestions for the overall code quality (like swallowing an exception and returning `false`, `go` boolean flag controlling the loop) - but this is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It turns out there <B>were</B> several million characters in the line. I've never had a problem previously with a stack trace not printing on a serious error, thus I don't include them explicitly.  Thanks for your analysis! Until you mentioned it I thought that Exception was a catchall for <B>all</B> exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

`BufferredReader.readLine` returns `null` if there is no data, it doesn't throw an exception. So change your code to to:

```
 while (go) {
     s = br.readLine();
     if (s = null) break;
```

instead of handling an exception. That's why your code never leaves the cycle and probably is trying to allocate memory infinitely.